# Cannot permanently delete certain files

Tags: finder, macos, trash, dropbox

I have this recurring problem where certain files can't be removed from my bin:

> The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “0000”
> can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

I'm pretty certain that the problem is related to the '*online-only*' feature of Dropbox. E.g. me deleting files that are in the cloud rather than stored on my hard drive.

I think the only way I could delete them would be to first restore them to their original folder, sync them with dropbox and then delete them again.

Surely there has to be a better way?

Comment: Did you try to completely quit DropBox prior emptying your trash bin? Make sure Dropbox finder service is turned off.

Comment: Just a thought, but what if you logged into your Dropbox account via a web browser and go into deleted files and remove any files there, might that work?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to fix it, I simply moved the files back into my Dropbox folder... and when Dropbox sync'd them, they magically disappeared!